Torah verse references with Latin and Greek letter designations
In the website, thetorah.com and specifically content inside the following https:
https://www.thetorah.com/article/israels-departure-from-egypt-a-liberation-or-an-escape
I've noticed Greek letters associated with the Latin letters, e.g., "14:20a-β." I understand the first 'a' refers to the first part of the verse but the Greek letters confuse me a bit. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

I think it may be a system to denote the way he re-constructed what he believes is the "original" text.  However, you will need to seek the author's answer.  See  https://www.thetorah.com/contact-us

That's a good idea Dottard. I've seen this referencing in other works such as Kraus' work on the Psalms.
